# Implemented generic class, getting Activity.this error

Tags: java, android, generics

I have implemented a generic class, I have defined the type `T` for the interface to `Integer`, I get error when calling `Activity.this` and instantiating adapter.

**error screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Integer> {

    private RecyclerView testRecycleView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

        testRecycleView = findViewById(R.id.test_recycleview);

        ArrayList<Pet> pet = new ArrayList<>();
        pet.add(new Pet("a","nothing"));
        pet.add(new Pet("b","nothing"));
        pet.add(new Pet("c","nothing"));
        pet.add(new Pet("d","nothing"));
        pet.add(new Pet("e","nothing"));

        RecyclerViewAdapter<Pet> adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter<Pet>(pet, this, R.layout.test_pet_row);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        testRecycleView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        testRecycleView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(Integer position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "clicked "+ position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Generic class**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter<T> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<T> mDataset;
    private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<T> onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
    private int layoutId;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<T> measurements, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<T> onRecyclerViewItemClickListener, int layoutId) {
        this.onRecyclerViewItemClickListener = onRecyclerViewItemClickListener;
        this.mDataset = measurements;
        this.layoutId = layoutId;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        RecyclerViewRow<T> row = (RecyclerViewRow<T>) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(row);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mRow.showData(mDataset.get(position));
        ((View) holder.mRow).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (onRecyclerViewItemClickListener != null) {
                    onRecyclerViewItemClickListener.onItemClick(mDataset.get(position));
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public RecyclerViewRow mRow;

        public ViewHolder(RecyclerViewRow itemView) {
            super((View) itemView);
            mRow = itemView;
        }
    }

    public interface RecyclerViewRow<T> {
        void showData(T item);
    }

    public interface OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<T> {
        void onItemClick(T position);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Pet>
```

instead of

```
implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Integer>
```

because you have

```
ArrayList<T> measurements, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<T> onRecyclerViewItemClickListener
```

so the both use "T"

new RecyclerViewAdapter sets T to "Pet", therefore T can't be "Integer" at the same time

Comment: thanks @JavaMan for your answer, but that doesn't seem to be issue. I have shared generic class code. Now you can see the constructor. maybe that helps :)

Comment: It says required type RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener but provided testActivity. This error arises when i define type to Integer when left blank doesn't cause issue. But i need to explicitly define that it's integer. I have also updated error screenshot.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Pet>'  instead of 'implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<Integer>'

because you have 'ArrayList<T> measurements, OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<T> onRecyclerViewItemClickListener' so the both use "T";
new RecyclerViewAdapter<Pet> sets T to "Pet"

Comment: yes actually, i didn't realize that :) can you update your answer, i will accept. Thank you very much.